# Databinding action cancels selectedindexchanging event

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, data-binding

I'm using ListView server control to represent some data. When I fire a Select command, Page does postback properly; but if i bind data source in pageload, selectedindexchanging event is being cancelled. I toggled databinding to comment in pageload and it worked properly.

Here is my databinding method.

```
    public void BindData()
    {
        lstSamples.DataSource = (Session["AnalyzeApp"] as AnalizBasvurusu).SampleInfos;
        lstSamples.DataKeyNames = new string[] {"Key"};

        lstSamples.DataBind();
    }
```

And i call it that way

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostback)
        BindData();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a question?  Is there a reason you need to handle `SelectedIndexChanging` instead of `SelectedIndexChanged` or `ItemCommand`?

Comment: Actually it cancels every event. Neither **OnItemCommand** nor **SelectedIndexChanged** etc. can be fired. It just does things in Page_Load when i bound data in Page_Load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `BindData()` after you handle your events(SelectedIndexChanging..etc):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostback)
        BindData();
}
```

Comment: thank you all, rick's solution worked well. But i didn't get exactly why. Binding data clears event stack or something?

Comment: Check out the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle and it will make sense, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx